# Changing date base on activity that has happened

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three fields 
ReviewDate (Dates reviews are set to happen)
Completeddate (Date review was completed)
NextDueDate (Date next review needs to happen which is 8wks + either Reviewdate or completeddate depends which happen lastest.

I will like my reviewdate to change base on the parameter above. Please see snip[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YikuW.png). for example I want my reviewdate on the third row to be 2020-03-03 instead of 20-01-27

```
ReviewDate  CompletedDate   NextDue_ReviewDate  
----------------------------------------------
2019-10-07  2019-10-07      2019-12-02          
2019-12-02  2020-01-07      2020-03-03          
2020-01-27  NULL            NULL                

    Select *, CASE WHEN Cast(ReviewDate as Date) > Cast(CompletedDate as Date) THEN DATEADD(WK,8,Convert(date,MAX(cast(ReviewDate as Date))))
               WHEN Cast(CompletedDate as Date) > Cast(ReviewDate as Date) THEN DATEADD(WK,8,Convert(date,MAX(Cast(CompletedDate as Date)))) ELSE DATEADD(WK,8,Convert(date,MAX(Cast(CompletedDate as Date))))
               END AS 'NextDue_ReviewDate',
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and_ the expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to images.

Comment: Hi Beejay, Welcome to SO. Please check this guideline for posting a good question. __> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: And why exactly do you feel the need to cast what should be (and what sounds like) a DATE to DATE?

Comment: Its a datetime value and I needed to get rid of the time

Comment: Not according to your code and sample data. Nor do you need to cast to compare them. Casting AFTERWARD - perhaps. And you have multiple rows - which implies that you have some column that "connects" the rows. And that's why you should include a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LAG function (if using SQL Server 2012 or above) to update the ReviewDate.

Please see the example [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a56c0d3373d3b8fa9bc415fb9ee89e0d).

Comment: Thanks for this response, that was very helpful. I just noticed that the difference between the dates is not up to 8 weeks. For example 2020-03-03 + 8weeks should be 2020-04-28

Answer (score 0):

You can define your table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  PersonID int,
  reportDate DATETIME,
  nextDate AS DATEADD(week, 8, reportDate)
);
```

This will compute the third column adding 8 weeks to the date entered in the second. Here is a demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b4eb4/1)